# Adding class active to menu items using JS, doesn't work on subpages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, url, menu

So I have this WordPess site that has a myriad of custom links in its menu, and I figured it would save me some time to simply set a class active to the current menu item using js instead, and jQuery in particular. Like so -

```
var url = window.location;
$('a[href*="' + url + '"]', 'header').addClass('active');
```

Goodbye php overhead!

Using this script I can't seem to set the class when on a single page though, even if the url partly matches a menu item (for example, a category name is in the menu and the url is /thatcategory/somepost/). Is there something that I can add to this script that would run it the same way on all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your trailing slashes match, so if there is a slash at the end of `window.location`, there needs to be one in your `href`. It might also help if you check if the links have a full domain in them or not.

**http//www.example.com/one/two** is not going to match a link with href **/one/two**

Might be worth looking into using `window.location.pathname` and match on that instead of the full URL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, solved it using document.location.href and then splitting up those paths.

Comment: Glad I could help! From what I can see, `document.location` is deprecated and not recommended. Use `window.location.href` instead.